# howto to load listView items in app

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I use Telerik Icenium for creating a mobile app, its just Cordova and Jquery mobile involved.

On the frontpage I have a listView like this

```
<ul data-role="listview">
                <li><a href="#OpenProject?pid=1" data-transition="slide">Project 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#OpenProject?pid=2" data-transition="slide">Project 2</a></li>
            </ul>
```

This I would like to load from local storage instead, and then when the user chooses so, I will synch that against my API.

Would it be a good way to use the localstorage and fetch them items from there? If so, could anyone give me a good way to load the items either from a local json file or from a local database on the mobile into the listView.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made you a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/W3YDd/

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){       
        if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined") {
            localStorage.jsonExample='[{"score":null,"popularity":3,"translated":true,"adult":false,"language":"en","original_name":"The Goonies","name":"The Goonies","alternative_name":"Балбесы","movie_type":"movie","id":9340,"imdb_id":"tt0089218","url":"http://www.themoviedb.org/movie/9340","votes":43,"rating":8.5,"certification":"PG","overview":"A young teenager named Mikey Walsh finds an old treasure map in his fathers attic. Hoping to save their homes from demolition, Mikey and his friends Data Wang, Chunk Cohen, and Mouth Devereaux run off on a big quest to find the secret stash of Pirate One-Eyed Willie.","released":"1985-06-06","posters":[{"image":{"type":"poster","size":"thumb","height":138,"width":92,"url":"http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/w92/bZUbpjwnarSHJK40W9sGpyedWhx.jpg","id":"4ea6009334f8633bdc002f61"}},{"image":{"type":"poster","size":"w154","height":231,"width":154,"url":"http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/w154/bZUbpjwnarSHJK40W9sGpyedWhx.jpg","id":"4ea6009334f8633bdc002f61"}},{"image":{"type":"poster","size":"cover","height":278,"width":185,"url":"http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/w185/bZUbpjwnarSHJK40W9sGpyedWhx.jpg","id":"4ea6009334f8633bdc002f61"}},{"image":{"type":"poster","size":"w342","height":513,"width":342,"url":"http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/w342/bZUbpjwnarSHJK40W9sGpyedWhx.jpg","id":"4ea6009334f8633bdc002f61"}},{"image":{"type":"poster","size":"mid","height":750,"width":500,"url":"http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/w500/bZUbpjwnarSHJK40W9sGpyedWhx.jpg","id":"4ea6009334f8633bdc002f61"}},{"image":{"type":"poster","size":"original","height":1500,"width":1000,"url":"http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/original/bZUbpjwnarSHJK40W9sGpyedWhx.jpg","id":"4ea6009334f8633bdc002f61"}}],"backdrops":[{"image":{"type":"backdrop","size":"thumb","height":169,"width":300,"url":"http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/w300/awhHFqiw6Dta0uHQVjgwQiyOgro.jpg","id":"4ffdbd7f760ee3570d0000e8"}},{"image":{"type":"backdrop","size":"poster","height":439,"width":780,"url":"http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/w780/awhHFqiw6Dta0uHQVjgwQiyOgro.jpg","id":"4ffdbd7f760ee3570d0000e8"}},{"image":{"type":"backdrop","size":"w1280","height":720,"width":1280,"url":"http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/w1280/awhHFqiw6Dta0uHQVjgwQiyOgro.jpg","id":"4ffdbd7f760ee3570d0000e8"}},{"image":{"type":"backdrop","size":"original","height":1080,"width":1920,"url":"http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/original/awhHFqiw6Dta0uHQVjgwQiyOgro.jpg","id":"4ffdbd7f760ee3570d0000e8"}}],"version":3350,"last_modified_at":"2013-03-19 13:57:18 UTC"}]';      
        }

    var jsonObject = jQuery.parseJSON(localStorage.jsonExample);

    $('#movie-data').append('<li>Movie name:<span> ' + jsonObject[0].original_name+ '</span></li>');
    $('#movie-data').append('<li>Popularity:<span> ' + jsonObject[0].popularity + '</span></li>');
    $('#movie-data').append('<li>Rating:<span> ' + jsonObject[0].rating+ '</span></li>');
    $('#movie-data').append('<li>Overview:<span> ' + jsonObject[0].overview+ '</span></li>');
    $('#movie-data').append('<li>Released:<span> ' + jsonObject[0].released+ '</span></li>');  
    $('#movie-data').listview('refresh'); 
});
```

For a better clarification, this example was created from my other example:

http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/jLdFj/

In this example json is acquired from a remote source. But basic principle is the same.

Comment: +1. You deleted your answer from a question earlier, why did you do that?

Comment: You have fixed your code and I gave you an upvote. No point of having 2 answers with same content. And on the other hand I am not here for a reputation, you take it :)

Comment: I improved it, thanks, learned a lot. I still need reputation to get all permission on this site, I want to improve it. Thank mate